# Need Help with determining Eigenvector of this Particular Singular Matrix ($\lambda = 0$)

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

It is my understanding that a singular matrix will always have an eigenvector of some values for eigenvalue = 0.

Let $$A =\begin{pmatrix} 2.25 && -2.25 \\ -2.25 && 2.25 \end{pmatrix}$$
Because $det(A) = 0$, therefore $A$ is a singular matrix.

Eigenvalues of $A$ are $4.5$ and $0$.
For eigenvalue $= 0$, here is a screenshot:

[image: Problem image]

Because $A$ is a singular matrix, there should be a solution for this eigenvector, right? Am I missing something?

Any help will be really appreciated, thank you! :)

Comment: $\lambda_2 = 0,   v_2 = (-0.707107, -0.707107)$. Also, if you change the decimals to fractions, you can arrive at: $\lambda_2 = 0,   v_2 = (1, 1)$.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your quick answer! I found that answer as well when I am using Octave. The problem is, I can't find a way to reach that conclusion. Can you give a me a step-by-step of the equation until it arrives at v2 = (-0.707, -0,707)? Thanks!

Comment: A singular matrix has a kernel.  Some set of vectors $v_n$ such that $Av_n$ = 0.  These vectors then are eigenvectors associated with the eigenvalue 0.

Comment: @Jackyef: When you form $[A- 0 I]v_2 = 0$ and find the RREF, what do you arrive at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simplicity, take $A = \left( \begin{matrix}1 & -1 \\ -1 & 1 \end{matrix} \right)$. Then for the eigenvector with eigenvalue $0$, we solve
$$A \left( \begin{matrix} x \\ y\end{matrix} \right) = 0 \left( \begin{matrix} x \\ y\end{matrix} \right) \iff \left( \begin{matrix} x-y \\ -x+y\end{matrix} \right) = \left( \begin{matrix} 0 \\ 0\end{matrix} \right).$$
This gives **two** equations which should be satisfied, namely
$$ x-y = 0 \text{ and } -x+y =0.$$
Thus $x=y$, where we are free to choose the value of $y\neq 0$.

The solution gives only one solution, $ x- y-x+y =0$ which is always satisfied. But as we want each coordinate the same, we must solve the system of **two** equations as above.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I needed.